# is "You Worry Not" a correct phrase?

Tags: grammaticality

I am trying to rephrase the "Don't worry" in such a way that it will sound more like a promise  than as advice.

I wonder if this is a wrong way to phrase that.

I actually copy that from love me not, which is "don't love me" rephrased

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In older forms of the language, this construction has been used repeatedly by great poets like Shakespeare, so it can't be considered "wrong", just dated and out of use. Personally, I would think it is poetic rather than wrong.

Another way to make this phrase more of a promise is ***Don't you worry***, which is more widely used today.

Comment: Or: "You needn't worry", perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of "love me not" would be "worry you not". Similarly, it sounds antiquated, and one might initially feel it looks wrong.

That said, it is just as much of a command (as is "love me not")!

As @Irene and @RandomIdeaEnglish pointed out on another answer, other forms would better convey your meaning.

Comment: Though correct, this would remind me irresistibly of Frankie Howerd's "Titter ye not" (which was, of course, guaranteed to start the audience tittering).

Comment: I have picked "Thou shall worry not" at the end. did I do right?

Comment: I think there's two problems with that: 1) it's a prediction, more than a suggestion  or advice; it "translates" to "You won't worry". 2) the correct form would be "Thou shalt worry not"

Comment: @TzuryBarYochay: I added a comment but forgot to reference your username, see above.

Comment: @Tao I want it to be "sound more like a promise" and I actually used shalt not shall. so I guess I ma fine after all

Comment: In general they use it as Don't worry and particularly in Australia it is used as no worries